# Which determiner to use before 'space race'

Tags: grammar, determiners

This was the conversation:

A : Why can't all space agencies work together for the better of humanity?

B : The space race, friend!

B meant the general meaning '**the competition between nations regarding achievements in the field of space exploration**', while A contended 'The space race' refers exclusively to the rivalry between the Soviet and the USA in the 1960's.

Comment: A contended nothing about the US/USSR space race. He did not say anything about the USSR or the USA specifically, he even says "**all** space agencies", which very much implies that his question is bigger than just the US/USSR. If this is part of a larger context (A having focused on the US/USSR at an earlier point), then you'll have to add that context.

Comment: @Flater B here wants to point out that due to the space race(the competitive nature of space exploration) they don't work together.. maybe the question is not clear in this regard

Comment: The question is indeed not clear; because the example by itself never mentioned anything about the US/USSR. That's only found in your explanation of the example (leading me to believe that it's a wrong inference on your part). As it stands, there is no reason to infer that either A or B are specifically talking about the US/USSR space race.

Comment: Just wondering what you're trying to ask. Was there something about "the" before "space race" that you found odd?

Comment: @flater Your comment clarifies it for me

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, when this person confronted me he said that when I say 'the competition between nations regarding achievements in the field of space exploration' I am defining 'a space race' and not 'The Space Race' which according to him is exclusively the USA and soviet face off in the 1960's

Comment: @peerless That context would have been helpful in the question.

Comment: @Lawrence agreed, I would have to edit it